# Is it possible in Python to pass keyword arguments to a function and use them *only* if the function has them

Tags: python, functional-programming

I am trying to make a functional map-like function which fully traverses a list or dict of arbitrary depth / shape, then map the provided function over it.

I have the map function working, and I have the function to feed to it working, but I do not like how "un-generalized" it is, in case I want to use it for the future.

The main problem is that it isn't clear to me how I can pass an arbitrary # of arguments to the function-to-be-mapped, and only pass on the arguments that are found in the function-to-be-mapped, while all others are silently dropped.

## Background

The mapping function and the function to be mapped are being used to create fake data:

1. I traverse the arbitrarily-shaped object
2. When I find a "proper" data type, then I swap what it has -- dummy example data -- for data generated from the *faker* package.

## Mapping Function

The full function is not that big, so I will just add the whole thing:

```py
def object_map(
    action: Callable,
    obj: Union[dict, list],
    coerce: bool,
    data_types: Tuple[type, ...] = avail_data_types,
    error_on_unknown: bool = False,
) -> Union[dict, list]:
    """Map an action across all values of interest in a dict or list of arbitrary depth.

    For instance, if you have a list of dicts, and some of the dicts have lists, but
    eventually each embedded list / dict ends with a type found in `data_types`, then
    the `action` will only be performed at this final leaf where a type in `data_types`
    is found.

    Parameters
    ----------
    action : Callable (function)
        The function which you wish to map onto *only `data_types`* leaves in the
        `obj` object.
    obj : dict or list
        The object of arbitrary depth that you wish to traverse.
    data_types : tuple, optional
        A tuple of data types that you want to allow the `action` to be performed upon.
        Note: the *order* of the tuple matters if you are coercing. If `str` is before
        `int`, for instance, then no strings will be coerced into integers. The type
        which you want to coerce into must be before the type you expect to coerce from.
        Defaults to a tuple of the keys found in `fake_generators` dict.
    coerce : bool
        Whether or not to coerce the elements into one of the `data_types`, if
        possible. Eg, should the string `'7.1'` be coerced into the float `7.1`.
    error_on_unknown : bool, optional
        Whether or not to error when neither a list, dict, nor any of the types found
        in `data_types` are found. If `True`, then a `NotImplementedError` will be
        generated. Otherwise, the element is kept in the object without performing any
        mapping. Defaults to `False`.

    Returns
    -------
    dict or list
        The original `obj`, traversed such that elements of type found in `data_types`
        have the function `action` mapped onto them.

    Examples
    --------
    >>> orig = {'elem1': [7, 5, 'apple', 13.1], 'elem2': {'extra1': '12'}}
    """
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        result = {}
        for key, val in obj.items():
            if isinstance(val, (dict, list)):
                result[key] = object_map(
                    action, val, coerce, data_types, error_on_unknown
                )
            elif isinstance(val, data_types):
                if not coerce:
                    result[key] = action(val)
                else:
                    for data_type in data_types:
                        try:
                            result[key] = action(data_type(val))
                        except (TypeError, ValueError):
                            pass
                        else:
                            # Once successful, don't keep generating further types.
                            break
            else:
                if error_on_unknown:
                    raise NotImplementedError(
                        "Only dicts and lists are allowed as iterables, and only "
                        f"{', '.join([val.__name__ for val in data_types])} allowed as "
                        f"single values. You provided `{val}`, which is none of these"
                    )
                else:
                    result[key] = val
    elif isinstance(obj, list):
        result = []
        for val in obj:
            if isinstance(val, (dict, list)):
                result.append(
                    object_map(action, val, coerce, data_types, error_on_unknown)
                )
            elif isinstance(val, data_types):
                if not coerce:
                    result.append(action(val))
                else:
                    for data_type in data_types:
                        try:
                            result.append(action(data_type(val)))
                        except (TypeError, ValueError):
                            pass
                        else:
                            # Once successful, don't keep generating further types.
                            break
            else:
                if error_on_unknown:
                    raise NotImplementedError(
                        "Only dicts and lists are allowed as iterables, and only "
                        f"{', '.join([val.__name__ for val in data_types])} allowed as "
                        f"single values. You provided `{val}`, which is none of these"
                    )
                else:
                    result.append(val)
    else:
        raise NotImplementedError(
            f"Only dicts and lists are allowed as iterables. You provided {obj}, "
            "which is none of these"
        )
    return result
```

## Function to be Mapped

This function is quite small, but I'll explain some of the unclear parameters after:

```py
D = TypeVar("D", *avail_data_types)
def gen_fake_data(
    entry: D,
    recover_type: bool = True,
    fake_generator_types: Dict[type, List] = fake_generators,
    fake_obj: Faker = fake,
):
    data_type = type(entry)
    try:
        generator = choice(fake_generator_types[data_type])
        result = getattr(fake_obj, generator)()
    except (TypeError, ValueError):
        data_types = tuple(fake_generator_types)
        raise NotImplementedError(
            f"Only {', '.join([val.__name__ for val in data_types])} supported for "
            f"fake data generation. You provided {entry}, which is none of these"
        )
    if recover_type:
        return data_type(result)
    else:
        return result
```

## Weakness with my Current Generalization

In the mapping function, I write things like:

```py
                    result[key] = action(val)
```

This means that I can *only* pass a `Callable` (a function) to `action` that only has 1 required parameter. As you can see, `data_types` and `coerce` are basically the same as what `gen_fake_data` needs (optional parameters `data_types` and `recover_type`). I would also pass those to the mapping function, `object_map`, except that then I have completely coupled these two functions together. That's no *so bad*, except that `object_map` could be quite useful for other work, too.

I'd like to be able to do something like

```py
                    result[key] = action(val, data_types=data_types, recover_type=coerce)
```

and just have those extra keywords (`data_types` and `recover_type`) just be ignored if the function `action` does not contain them in its parameters, so that it silently converts to

```py
                    result[key] = action(val)
```

when the keywords are not found.

***Is there any way to do this in Python?***

**Or instead, is there a better way that I can construct these two functions so that the mapping function is still generalized in how it can manage the function-to-be-mapped?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dicts and keyword-only arguments for this.

```py
def action_foo(__val, /, **kwargs):
    '''
    this action takes the obligatory argument val, 
    and keyword argument foo.
    '''
    foo = kwargs['foo']  # will raise a KeyError if missing
    print(f"doing foo({__val}, {foo=})")


def action_bar(__val, /, **kwargs):
    '''
    this action takes the obligatory argument val, 
    and keyword argument bar.
    '''
    bar = kwargs['bar']
    print(f"doing bar({__val}, {bar=})")


def action_baz(__val, /, **kwargs):
    '''
    this action takes the obligatory argument val, 
    and keyword argument baz.
    '''
    baz = kwargs['baz']
    print(f"doing baz({__val}, {baz=})")

# pass arguments as a dictionary
keyword_args = {
    'foo': 'FUS',
    'bar': 'ROH',
    'baz': 'DAH'
}
for i, action in enumerate([action_foo, action_bar, action_baz]):
    action(i, **keyword_args)

# or as key words like this if you prefer
for i, action in enumerate([action_foo, action_bar, action_baz]):
    action(i, foo='FUS', bar='ROH', baz='DAH')
```

Prints the following :

```
doing foo(0, foo='FUS')
doing bar(1, bar='ROH')
doing baz(2, baz='DAH')
```

As an added benefit, insted of looking up the item using `kwargs['name']`, you can use the `pop` method, which supports a default return value. (i.e. `kwargs.pop('name', 'Tim')`
This also lets you track if any unexpected keyword arguments were passed : if you `pop` every expected `kwarg`, and `len(kwargs) > 0`, you know you user passed an unexpected argument, so you can raise a `TypeError`.